How to write ES module having both default and named export?
I want to make my ES module importable in both following styles:
import * as mylib from "./mylib.mjs";
import mylib from "./mylib.mjs";

Then I wrote mylib.mjs in following style:
export function foo(){
}
export function bar(){
}
export function baz(){
}
// ... and many export functions...(1)
export default {foo, bar, baz, /* ... and many function names...(2) */};

But I always have to worry about some names missing in export default(2). If a new export functions(1) is added, I have to add it also in function names(2). I often forget this.
In CommonJS, using exports makes this smarter. Is there any variable that is equivalent to exports in ES module?
exports.foo=function () {
};
exports.bar=function () {
};
exports.baz=function () {
};
exports.default=exports;// No need to change here when function export is added.


“I want to make my ES module importable in both following styles” – do you have a good reason for this? It seems much worse than just settling on import * as mylib.

What you are trying to do is a code smell to me and to me indicate low quality code written by a non-js programmer. IMHO the correct answer is to not do it

Why all the downvotes? Whether it is advisable or not, it's a valid question and people can do what they want.

using import mylib from "./mylib.mjs" instead of import * as mylib from "./mylib.mjs" looks not good, confusing, DRY/SSOT is broken to some degree

I would argue namespace imports (import * as) are an anti pattern. Why, because es modules can import cjs modules and node tries to determine the named exports but the process is not perfect so they recommend the default import approach for better compatibility. For instance namespace.foo might throw a reference error if foo was not detectable via their heuristic. The airbnb style guide also recommends against it. Better to be specific and just use named exports.

Sometimes you need a default export, for instance react lazy loading, but I’d stay away from them in general, and relying on tree shaking from bundlers, et al. and always using namespace imports is only inviting potential confusion and a possibly bloated module graph imo.

This is not something I would advise doing as I feel barrel files are an anti-pattern, and it is better to have one way for loading your modules, but something you could do to get close to what you want is to organize your project like this:
.
└── src/
    ├── mylib/
    │   └── mod.mjs
    ├── mylib.mjs
    └── consumer.mjs

mylib/mod.mjs
export function foo(){
}
export function bar(){
}
export function baz(){
}

mylib.mjs
export * from './mylib/mod.mjs'
export * as default from './mylib/mod.mjs'

consumer.mjs
import * as mylibNs from './mylib.mjs'
import mylib from './mylib.mjs'

Requires an extra file to manage the the exports, but you won't have to update the exported names in multiple places.
Of course if you're ok with circular references in your modules, you can have just one file like this:
mylib.mjs
export function foo() {
}
export function bar() {
}
export function baz() {
}

export * as default from './mylib.mjs'

It would be consumed the same way as before, but the default property would be a reference back to the module itself, i.e. mylib.default === mylib.
This was tested using Node.js v20.12.0.
